# MVC C# - GET Request is Working, POST is giving me an error. How do I debug?

Tags: c#, post, model-view-controller

I am taking a beginner course in ASP.NET MVC for webapps and am having some issues with the API section. My GET request (using Postman) is pulling data in JSON fine, but my POST request is giving me an Invalid ModelState error. I'm not sure what in the model is invalid so am looking for assistance or guidance in how to debug

My GET request from postman spits out the customers in the database.
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Jimmy Steve",
        "IsSubscribedToNewsleter": true,
        "MembershipType": null,
        "MembershipTypeId": 4,
        "CustomerBirthday": "2018-01-01T00:00:00"
    }

I then copy the above, remove the ID section and change the Name and submit as a POST request and I get a 400 bad request error from the ModelState not valid error.

I'm not sure what is wrong in my model that is not allowing me to POST.

Here is the controller code:

```
   //GET
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return _context.Customers.ToList();
    }


     //Post
    [HttpPost]
    public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)

    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return customer;
    }
```

Here is the model code:

```
    public class Customer


{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsleter { get; set; }

    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
    public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [Min18YearsIfAMember]
    public DateTime? CustomerBirthday { get; set;}

}
```

And here is the form code:

```
<h2>Create Customer</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Customers"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.CustomerBirthday)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.CustomerBirthday, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.CustomerBirthday)
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsleter) Subscribed to Newsletter
        </label>
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Id)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I feel like it has something to do with a field being required - but I am submitting all fields in the post request so am not sure where I'm going wrong. Any ideas or tips on debugging would be greatly appreciated!

edit: Save code below

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(Customer customer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
        {
            Customer = customer,
            MembershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList()
        };

        return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
    }

    if (customer.Id == 0)
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);

    else
    {
        var customerInDb = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);

        customerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
        customerInDb.CustomerBirthday = customer.CustomerBirthday;
        customerInDb.MembershipTypeId = customer.MembershipTypeId;
        customerInDb.IsSubscribedToNewsleter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsleter;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
}
```

Comment: Invalid Model States will only appear if youre using DataAnnotations which appears like youre using the built in one on the name attribute and a custom one on the CustomerBirthday attribute. I'd look into the     [Min18YearsIfAMember]
custom attribute and see if youre passing correct data to satisfy that attribute

Comment: check out the errors by replacing the throw error code temporarily with `return string.Join(", ", ModelState.SelectMany(m => m.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)))`

Comment: Where is the code for the 'Save' method?

Comment: @JamesS Thanks for the help - I added the save code now.

Comment: Where abouts are you getting this error? In the post to the save or when you try and create a customer?

Comment: @JamesS when I run the save action from the webapp it saves a customer to the database just fine. When I run the httppost CreateCustomer in postman is when I'm getting the model state error, I'm just not sure where to look because the GetCustomer action is working fine in Postman.

Comment: So what it's saying is when the modelstate is not valid. throw an exception. Are there objects in the customer class that need set?

Comment: @Daniel I commented out the Min18Year rule and got it working! Will dig into that now but thank you for the help!!